# Mysql : An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'rlike'

Tags: perl, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I need to match large strings with the fields of a column in mysqlDB. something like

**%ERROR-kkl_ub{}: (from YAMios): Destination (name = sdasdays.s0sda.rindasdth.sbo98.sbssdao_sad) is not registered.**

i pass this string to a variable say $signautre.

and am using this mysql command

```
    $query = "select id, name, status "."from bucket "."where name rlike '$signature'";
    &execQuery($query);
```

i get the error : FATAL ERROR: Operation failed execQuery() - Error in execQuery. An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'rlike'

i am not able to do even a simple match using "rlike".
even this command errors out with the same Fatal error.

```
    $query = "select id, name, status "."from bucket "."where name rlike '^n'";
```

need help...

Comment: Why do you need `rlike`? Please define the word `match` in "I need to match large strings"

Comment: the 'name' column in my db has large strings just like the one, i have given above. i will be given such patterns by my customer and i will need to match then with the values in column 'name' and extract corresponding data from the other fields like id and status.

both rlike and regex , give me the same error.
i not these do you have anyother way of doing this??

Comment: obviously the pattern is incorrect

Comment: what would you suggest, i need to do, to match such a large pattern??

Comment: you didn't explain what you mean by saying `match`

Comment: match would be say if i had $signature = mango; i would have to find this value "mango" in the db.

i need to get the id and status for this name (%ERROR-kkl_ub{}: (from YAMios): Destination (name =sdasdays.s0sda.rindasdth.sbo98.sbssdao_sad) is not registered.) in the db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your explanation in the comments you just need `=`:

```
$query = "select id, name, status from bucket where name = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($signature) . "'";
```

In this case mysql checks if the `name` field is **exactly equal** to the `$signature`

ps: `&` in `&execQuery($query);` makes no sense

Comment: i am writing a perl script, using a HSDapi to access the DB. it says this sub routine (mysql_real_escape_string) is not defined. Which api do i need to install to be able to access this sub routine??

Comment: I thought you use `php` (because of `mysqli` specified). Well - you need to find how to quote string for queries in perl then